# JQuery Window.Open onload not working for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, onload

I'm having an issue with IE using a window.open onload function. From what I've read on other posts, apparently it's because the body of the IE page isn't loaded before the function runs. I've tried a multitude of examples, but I can't seem to get any to work.
Here's the code:

```
var popup = window.open('shared/message.html','_blank','width=770,height=800');
  popup.onload = function() {
  popup.document.title = "subject";
  $(popup.document.body).append('content');
};
```

This works on Chrome. It opens a new window and changes the page title and populates the page with "content". But for IE for some reason the onload doesn't fire.

- I've tried to use a timer, to wait about 1 second before firing the onload.
- I've tried using a check if the `popup.document.body` exists before firing.

I've tried a few more, but I can't remember them now, and all of them work on chrome, but I still can't get IE to load. And yes, I have to find an IE solution please.

I was considering maybe a way to "pass" information to the new window, like an ID or something then I can add an even listener to that popup page to load the content that way. But I have to use the popup for other content too, so I can't hard code the content.

To put some context to what I'm doing here: Essentially I have a "home" page that populates a list of SharePoint items from an announcements list. When the user clicks on one of the items, it opens a new window with all the content on it. I'm using SPServices GetListItems to extract the content. Then I'm using the popup.onload to add 'content' as the body HTML for the new window.

I hope I've explained myself accordingly, thank you in advance for your ideas. Let me know if you want to see my SPServices code, again though, I know it's the IE thing because Chrome works like a charm.

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. On the Console tab of the IE dev tool you will now see markup and blocked content/security messages. IE has a security setting preventing navigation into a zone of lower integrity.. the security zone mapping of your message.htm must be the Intranet zone. Third-party popup blockers can also affect scripted window outcomes. File>Properties will tell you which zone a page/domain maps to.

Comment: It is unusual to use client side scripting on asp.net or sharepoint to populate a web page.... SharePoint has built in reports/forms for that purpose.